# transform a dataframe to list ans delete NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, nan

hi I have the following dataset

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'fruits': ['orange', 'mango', 'apple', 'grapes', 'NaN', 'mango'],
                   'price': ['40', '80', 'NaN', '40', '30', '80']
                   })

    fruits  price
0   orange  40
1   mango   80
2   apple   NaN
3   grapes  40
4   NaN     30
```

I want to return a list that does not have the NaN values. So I am using the following code:

```
dfd= [[y for y in x if pd.notna(y)] for x in df.values.tolist()]
```

However, the NaN values are still there

```
[['orange', '40'],
 ['mango', '80'],
 ['apple', 'NaN'],
 ['grapes', '40'],
 ['NaN', '30'],
 ['mango', '80']]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: So you want to lists of length 1 in the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `NaN` is string `pd.notna` return `False`, if need remove `'NaN's` strings use:

```
dfd= [[y for y in x if Y != 'NaN'] for x in df.values.tolist()]
```

If convert `NaN`s strings to missing values:

```
df = df.replace('NaN', np.nan)
dfd= [[y for y in x if pd.notna(y)] for x in df.values.tolist()]
```